# How to read/understand advertised fund performance figures?

Tags: mutual-funds, index-fund

Apologies if this has been asked before, I couldn't find it, or if this is so basic, but I feel it needs asking.

I'm sure we've all seen tables like this outlining fund performance.

[image]

What I'm unclear on is how to interpret those return values.

Say for example I put $100 in FundA, and it performs like this (extreme values to make my point clearer)

```
Year    Value of my account   Performance %
2010    $100
2011    $10                   -90%
2012    $20                   +100%
2013    $40                   +100%
2014    $80                   +100%    
2015    $100                  +25%
```

Would the "5 Year Return" advertised by a bank, in a table like the one above be:

a) 0% - because I started with $100 and ended with $100

or

b) 47% - the average of -90, 100, 100, 100, 25

I would expect and hope the answer is 'a', but... is it?

EDIT: Here's the advertised fund

https://www.td.com/ca/markets-research/mutual/mutual.jsp

and here's a Google Doc Sheet with the numbers, none of them match the advertised performance

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bn_e9wLKxF4dDJtzCh2VkGAW7jI4iyrMqO4m4iA6rDw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: That td link is generic.  Which specific fund are you referring to?

Comment: @RonJohn Sorry, it's 
TD Canadian Bond Index - eTDB909, choose "Mutual Funds" tab, then "Index Funds" in the now visible tab.  Then "Performance" in the new tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are *annualized* returns not *average annual* returns.  One formula for annualized return over a period (assuming continuous compounding) is

```
V1 - V0
-------  * e^(-T)
   V0
```

To convert to annual compounding you'd use:

```
 V1 - V0
--------- ^ (1/T) 
    V0
```

Where `V1` is the ending value, `V0` is the starting value, and `T` is the time frame in years.  Since `V1 - V0 = 0`, the annualized return over 5 years using either method is 0%.

Answer (score 2):

You **know** the answer, but wish it wasn't so.

EDIT: To get from $100 to $114.46 in 5 years is 3.434% compound growth. 100*1.3434<sup>4</sup>.  Since most stocks pay dividends, your account balance will not exactly reflect the growth in the price of the mutual fund.

Comment: I woke up in a cold sweat thinking maybe it was 'b' - that's true.